# Read pc volume percentage?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, arduino-nano

is there a way to read the current pc volume? This is going to be a part of a project that I have in mind that is essentially reading curent pc volume value and giving it an RGB value (green=>30, yellow=<30>60, red=<60) and lighting up an RGB led accordingly.

Comment: Please describe a little better what you want to read. pc = PC = Personal Computer (maybe with Windows)? Do you want to read if the volume slider is set i.e. to 30% or do you want to "read" how much noise comes out of the speakers?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the capabilities of PC operating systems are not on topic here - and doubly so when the operating system in question has not been identified.  Needless to say, if you obtain a number by some means, you can transmit it to your embedded system.  And no, Nick Alexeev, this is not an Arduino question either - it is a PC operating system question, and at presently too broad even for a site about those.  SE policy prohibits the migration of unanswerable questions and requires that they be closed at the source.

Comment: You guessed it the system is windows and I want to read the precentage that windows has in volume manager I know there are many HID librarys that can increase or decrease the volume but I have not seen any that can be used to pull the value. @chris Stratton https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/2zp22c/how_im_sure_most_firstposters_on_stackoverflow/

Comment: No, I stated the operating system was unspecified.  And irrelevant here.  How to obtaining settings information for PC operating systems, regardless if they are identified or not, is not a a permitted topic on this site, full stop.  SE sites are not traditional discussion forums, they are an *intentionally narrow* format, strictly separated by topics not permitted to overlap.

Comment: Well aren't you just a perfect specimen of the SE community and reputation

Comment: It seems like SE is not right for your needs.  And indeed, there is more than *does not* fit within this system than the very narrow set of things which does.  But that's what *this* is about.  Doesn't mean I agree with that, but it is what it is.  There's a whole remainder comprising merely... *every non-SE site on the global Internet* to satisfy other needs and approaches.

Comment: The easiest way would be writing a program, that runs in the PC and sends the current volume and any change to the Arduino via Serial. Investigate how to interface system volume in the PC with your chosen programming language (for example python).

Comment: @ChrisStratton This question is perfectly on topic. It may not be worded well, but the question is essentially "Can the Arduino be programmed to do X" where the answer is "No, it can't, but there are other routes you could investigate".  The question is not "How do I program the PC to do X", which *would* be off topic.

Comment: @Majenko - sorry, but you are completely wrong.  Read the question again "is there a way to read the current pc volume?"  That has nothing to do with Arduino.  If the poster could do that, then sending the result to an Arduino could be on topic, (if utterly trivial) but that's not the question that was asked.  Instead, a question about an unidentified PC operating system was asked.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Whatever. If my reading of the question is so wrong, how come my answer is accepted as correct? If you paid attention to the kind of questions asked here you'd know that people often ask about the Arduino querying information from the host PC in this kind of manner. You have to learn to read between the lines with Arduino users.

Comment: This question had a number of well deserved close votes from people who actually understand the rules of this site.  Those should not have been wiped out.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: when the highest rated guy on the site (by 2x) corrects you about site practice, consider he might know somewhat more than you about the site...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way for any hardware device, Arduino or otherwise, to request information like that from a computer.

HID is a protocol which (when used as a keyboard) allows you to *send* keypresses, including "media keys", which tell the computer to change the volume (amongst other things). There is no provision, other than three status LEDs, for getting any data back from the computer.

You will have to write software for your computer to query that information using whatever API may be available for your operating system, and pass that information through whatever communication channel you choose to the Arduino (such as through serial).

Some pointers:

- [C# get master volume level/precent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235246/c-sharp-get-master-volume-level-precent)
- [Windows 7 Master Volume](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/440743/Windows-Master-Volume)
- [Arduino: Sending and Receiving Multi-Digit Integers](https://www.baldengineer.com/arduino-multi-digit-integers.html)

Answer (score 1):

There are external devices that show the volume, but you need a driver for that. I don't know if there is an open source driver which you could adapt to send the volume via a serial port to the Arduino.

The Windows PowerShell has the possibility to get the volume and transmit it to a serial port. You could do that a few times per second. In linux it might even be easier, a bash script with gawk with "amixer sget Master".

Another problem is to select the right serial port for the Arduino. I don't know how to automatically select the right port.